# Do something when orientation changes – Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, orientation

I have a subclass of UIView where I'm having a collection of rects. I want the order of them to change when the device's orientation is changed. I can set the frames of each rect like this:

```
if (orientation == UIInterFaceOrientationPortrait)
{
    rect.frame = CGRectMake(100,100,200,300);
}
```

But I want a way to check whenever the device is being rotated, so directly when it is, the rects are doing something. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIDevice's` `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications` method and subscribe to the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDevice/beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications

Comment: Can you please give an exemple on how it can be used?

Comment: Take a look here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AlternateViews/Listings/PortraitViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008755-PortraitViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_10